# Gmail blocks my contact form mail sending attempt

Tags: joomla-3.4, configuration, smtp

I have added contact form for my Joomla 3.4.5 web site's contact page. All my mail settings in Configuration Manager are correct... But after submitting the message as a test intention, I get e-mail from Gmail that says

*it has blocked a sign-in attempt by an application which does not complies with **modern security standards***

As a result, I get

> SMTP connect() failed.
>
> SMTP connect() failed.

My configuration.php file contains those lines in the following:

```
...
public $mailonline = '1';
public $mailer = 'smtp';
public $mailfrom = 'my_gmail_account@gmail.com';
public $fromname = 'FROM NAME';
public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
public $smtpauth = '1';
public $smtpuser = 'my_gmail_account@gmail.com';
public $smtppass = 'my_gmail_account_password';
public $smtphost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
public $smtpsecure = 'ssl';
public $smtpport = '465';
...
```

PS: Authentication Gmail Plug-in is enabled.

Comment: Is this the default Joomla contact form?

Comment: @Lodder yes, it is..

Comment: If you allow less secure apps in your Gmail settings does it work? Not a permanent fix of course but worth testing. See here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

This issue is because Google have locked down their email system and require's apps to be authenticated first. With Joomla! this isn't possible at present, so you need to enable the 'less' secure option on your gmail account. See:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Once done, set SMTP Security to TLS and Port to: 25 with Authentication enabled. Note, these can be configured in the Joomla! Global configuration. No need to edit a file.

Many thanks
Tony

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  Un +1 for the last tip. Configuration can be modified in both ways

Comment: You are welcome, depending on the server SSL will not always work, so as an answer it's easier to specify TLS to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have read what Google says about enabling less secure option. Then switched to it. But I still get that error..

Comment: @zkanoca did you try as tls? What are your settings now?